# How to solve $x' = A\cdot x$?

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve this equation `x' = A x` in which `x'` is  a `1*18`, `A` is a `18*18` and `x` is a `1*18` matrix. I tried

```
NDSolve[Table[XXd[[i]] == AX[[i]], {i, 18}], XX, {t, 0, 2}]
```

but it does not work. I have to mention that

```
XXd = x'
AX = A.x
```

Do you guys have any suggestions?

PS:
I want to obtain x. If I go with

DSolve[Table[XXd[[i]] == AX[[i]], {i, 18}], XX, t]

it says "A very large output was generated". That is why I want to use NDSolve. When I use NDSolve it asks me for Initial Condition and when I enter them it is saying "Equation or list of equations expected" but my initial conditions are simple numbers.

-A ia a Matrix 18*18

-AX=A.XX

- XX = Table[Subscript[X, i][t], {i, 1, 18}];
- XXd = Table[Subscript[X, i]'[t], {i, 1, 18}];

Comment: Use the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse, `PseudoInverse[ ]`.

Comment: If by "solve" you mean find `xp` ($x^\prime$) when $A$ and $x$ are given... well, then simply `xp = A.x`.  If instead you want to find $x$ given $A$ and $x^\prime$, then `x = PseudoInverse[A].xp`.

Comment: Check the documentation for `NDSolve`, matrix-times-vector notation (`Dot`), notation for derivatives (`D`) for a start.

Comment: `NDSolve` must have initial conditions.

Comment: I am not quite certain whether you really want `NDSolve` or simply e.g. `LinearSolve`. However, either way, the requirements on the inputs are given in the documentation, and thus I vote to close. I suggest clarifying the question with a (simplified) motivating example if you want more concrete suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a 3x3 example -- is this what you need?

```
A = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == A.x[t], x[0] == {1, 1, 1}}, x, {t, 0, 2}][[1]];
x[2] /. sol
(* {4.11929*10^13, 9.32856*10^13, 1.45378*10^14} *)
```